# Unit/integration test a dao that consists of generic methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics

here are examples of a methods :

```
public <T> T save(final T o){
  return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(o);
}

public <T> T get(final Class<T> type, final Long id){
  return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(type, id);
}

public <T> List<T> getFieldLike(final Class<T> type, final String propertyName,
            final String value, final MatchMode matchMode)  {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(type);
    crit.add(Restrictions.like(propertyName, value, matchMode));
    return crit.list();
}
```

Any tips on either unit or integration test these ? Pass in a mock session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only thing you could do in a unit test is mock Session and Criteria and set expectations - I've done this for a few cases using JMock and ended up having to write a Hamcrest matcher for the Restricitons. I'm not convinced there's much value in it, other than blindly increasing the test coverage.

On the other hand - writing an integration test here would be of definite use, set up an in memory database with some data and assert that the methods return the correct objects

Comment: What of instead of mocking the session, we mock the dao itself and then emulate criteria restrictions with simple if / else operations on a small mock array? Sure, it does put some stress on the developer to write a proper mock, but I can see some benefits there. It's always nice to see how other people do it, though.

Answer (score 0):

An example for integration test for get():

```
// if you can inject the object:
// @Inject 
// public MyTestDAO<MyType> dao;
// 

@Test
public testGet() throws Exception {
    Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    MyTestDAO<MyType> dao = new MyTestDAO<MyType>();
    // if you use DI facility, check against null
    // assertNotNull(dao)
    MyType myType = dao.get(Test.class, 1L);
    assertNotNull(myType);
    assertEqual(myType, equalObj);
    // more asserts? 
}
```

if you use spring framework, you can use spring-test module to use DI using spring context and class runner:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring.xml"})
```

Answer (score 0):

By your question I assume you are managing your sessions yourself. I will talk about the unit testing part. Integration tests can be done on an in memory database during integration. H2 or Derby are one of the most used ones as far as I know.

You can go by passing a mock session to your DAO, but what will happen if one of your colleagues writes a unit test and forgets to pass a mock session? Do you hit database? If you DO NOT want to hit database, this approach can be a problem

What a better approach would be to use an abstract factory pattern to even ACQUIRE the dao. Basically your code is currently like this:

```
MyDao.get(someId);
```

However, you can go in the following way:

If you define your Dao first like this:

```
public interface IDao <SomeGenerics> {
   public <T> T get(Class<T> type, ID key);
   //more generic methods
}
```

Then you can have an implementation of the Dao, which is like this:

```
public class MyDao <SomeGenerics> implements IDao<SomeGenerics> {
    public <T> T get(Class<T> type, ID key){
        //some real session stuff
    }
    //...more real session stuff
}
```

Then in your unit tests you can define a mock of your IDao interface, kinda like this:

```
public class MyDaoMock <SomeGenerics> implements IDao<SomeGenerics> {
    //this thingy can hold a small array of mock instances
    private ArrayList<T> mockInstances;

    public <T> T get(Class<T> type, ID key){
        //some fake stuff, kinda like this;
        for (T mockInstance : mockInstances) {
               if ( mockInstance.getId().equals(key) ) {//here i assume your T has a method getId, you figure out the kinks
                     return mockInstance;
               }
        }
        //if not found, emulate your persistence's behavior, return null, throw an exception or do whatever
        return null;

    }
    //...more fake stuff
}
```

Now you have an interface and two implementations, one for your production code and one for your unit tests. Now all you have to do is to implement the factory pattern to give you the right dao in production and in testing code.